# Meaning of "objective thinking" in the mentioned context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I know the meaning of "objective thinking" but what does it mean in the following context?

> We all strive for safety, prosperity, comfort, long life, and dullness. The deer strives with his supple legs, the cowman with trap and poison, the statesman with pen, the most of us with machines, votes, and dollars, but it all comes to the same thing: peace in our time. A measure of success in this is all well enough, and perhaps is a requisite to **objective thinking**, but too much safety seems to yield only danger in the long run.

([Eco-Action](http://www.eco-action.org/dt/thinking.html))

I guess it doesn't here have the meaning it has in science or philosophy. But then I don't know what other meaning I should asign to it. Does it mean something like "wisdom"? 
**Objective thinking** sometimes is contrasted with **emotional thinking**. [Source](http://www.shlomifish.org/n-t-/neo-tech/Neo-Tech/advantage94.html). The question is how "peace in our time" is a requisite to objective thinking.

Comment: It means that unless we have food and shelter and some confidence that we will continue to have food and shelter we can think about nothing else.  But if we become too wedded to thinking about food and shelter and security and nothing else, we will be in danger of losing it all.

Comment: "Objective" is as opposed to "subjective".

Comment: I can't believe that people don't know what [cowman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vg5cwSBnyQU) means.  Is it just Brits that don't understand this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*First, a note about "cowman."  I understand it because (embarrassing cough) I listen to "The Archers" on BBC4, which has a character who is a "pigman", or someone who raises pigs.  But I had never heard it before.*

I will restate all but the last bit:

> We all seek stability.  The deer does, the cattle or dairy farmer does, the politician does, the normal Joe does, but it all boils down to the same thing: stability. Stability is good, and maybe you need to have stability in order to be able to set aside subjective concerns enough to be able to think objectively; but....

The last part is the part that I personally don't really understand.  But more context would probably help.  (I won't ask you for more context, because you didn't ask about the last bit.)

*My restatement isn't intended to be beautiful, just very simple and clear.*

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vg5cwSBnyQU

Answer (score 0):

(Wow, what you pose is not easy piece to parse.  Plus I couldn't even get to "objective thinking" until I had looked up "cowman".)

My sense of this is that *objective thinking* has its normal meaning, but in almost a derogatory way. It parallels *dullness* in the first sentence. This is a call to action, but one buried by its literary overhead.  The next sentence in the quote reads:

> Perhaps this is behind Thoreau's dictum: In wildness is the salvation of the world.

Simplified, I believe the author is saying something like, "Wake up you sleeping bastards, fight!"

For greater context, the author is [Aldo Leopold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldo_Leopold), 1887-1948, an American author, philosopher, scientist, ecologist, forester, conservationist, and environmentalist. The piece quoted by the OP is called *Thinking Like a Mountain* and has a "save the wolves" theme. (That's how the damn cowman snuck in, with his "trap and poison".)

Comment: The cited sentence looks to me like a total non-sequitur (why on earth should success in achieving "peace in our time" be a necessary precondition for objective thinking?). But to be honest, given that this writer characterises typical "tools of the trade" for ***cowmen*** as ***trap and poison***, I wouldn't be too interested in what he might have meant anyway.

Comment: I don't get how it parallels dullness. I get the general meaning or message of the text, but I am trying to understand the text word by word. And, what do you mean until you had looked up "cowman"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think the author is postulating that objective thought is unlikely if our primary focus is on active self-preservation; only after our safety and well-being is reasonably assured do we have the luxury of turning our minds away from emotion-driven, reactionary thinking.

Comment: @FumbleFingers As you were commenting, I was adding a paragraph identifying the piece's author and its subject. Given the subject, traps and poison are not out of context in regard to their adverse effect on wolves. Until I realized what the bigger picture was, a lot of it seemed like non-sequitur to me as well. But the paragraph is intentionally like inside-out balloon, what you think he is saying is the opposite of his meaning.

Comment: @RichF what is it saying then?

Comment: @NWR based on our previous discussion on this text, I though you might like to say your view.

Comment: @Jooya I don't think you can't read this "word by word". It is in a dense, old-fashioned literary style, more like Dickens than any modern author. Everything depends on everything else, and things overlap. Leopold's use of "dullness" is key, I think, the clue to what the words appear to say is not what they mean. Don't be dull. Don't be objective. Don't seek peace. The wolves need you.  Nature needs you. Wake the f*** up!

Comment: @Jooya I was not familar with the word "cowman".  It is not a common word in the USA.  I had to look it up to find its meaning. Like you, I started "word by word".  When the pieces didn't fit, I realized it was like a picture puzzle with the pieces needing to be arranged and rotated before it would all fit together.

Comment: @RichF Seriously? "cowman" is not a common word?

Comment: @Jooya Seriously.  We would use "dairy farmer", "rancher", or maybe "cowboy". Actually, I can't speak for all the USA.  Maybe it is just me who is ignorant of that word

Comment: @RichF You haven't seen enough old Western movies.

Comment: Any American who does not know what "cowman" means didn't watch enough westerns on TV as a child.